# How do I make parts of a URL to increment at the same time in cURL?

Tags: shell, command-line, curl, terminal

I'm using cURL to download files to a local folder. The command I'm using looks like this:

```
curl -O http://example.com/example/file[001-030]_file_[1-30]_eng.ext
```

I want the numbers to increment at the same time ("file001_file_1_eng.ext") so they match up. Instead this is working like a nested loop and the command is writing a bunch of empty files to the folder along with the existing files. So I get:

```
file001_file_1_eng.ext
file001_file_2_eng.ext <--- file doesn't exist
file001_file_3_eng.ext <--- file doesn't exist
```

etc...

So, I'm wondering how to get them to increment in the correct way.

I'm looking to get this output:

```
example.com/example/file008_file_1_eng.text 
example.com/example/file009_file_2_eng.text
example.com/example/file010_file_3_eng.text 
example.com/example/file011_file_4_eng.text 
example.com/example/file012_file_5_eng.text 
example.com/example/file013_file_6_eng.text 
example.com/example/file014_file_7_eng.text 
example.com/example/file015_file_8_eng.text 
example.com/example/file016_file_9_eng.text ... and so on.
```

Comment: How do you get create the numbers in a loop now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might want to use a [`for`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops1.html) loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {0..30}; do
    printf -v url "http://example.com/example/file%03d_file_%d_eng.text" $i $i
    curl -O $url
done
```

With this loop, the url's the you should get are the following ones:

```
http://example.com/example/file000_file_0_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file001_file_1_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file002_file_2_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file003_file_3_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file004_file_4_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file005_file_5_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file006_file_6_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file007_file_7_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file008_file_8_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file009_file_9_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file010_file_10_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file011_file_11_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file012_file_12_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file013_file_13_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file014_file_14_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file015_file_15_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file016_file_16_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file017_file_17_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file018_file_18_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file019_file_19_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file020_file_20_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file021_file_21_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file022_file_22_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file023_file_23_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file024_file_24_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file025_file_25_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file026_file_26_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file027_file_27_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file028_file_28_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file029_file_29_eng.text
http://example.com/example/file030_file_30_eng.text
```

Comment: Thanks: @jcollado, I'm still having trouble with the fact that the numbers in the URL don't match up. Ex: http://example.com/example/file035_file_1_eng.text. I've tried creating new variables to fix this but can't seem to get it working right. Maybe I'm off track.

Comment: @honestinjun With the code in the answer I don't see such a behaviour. Please, could elaborate on what are you running to get the wrong file names?

Comment: Sorry, my reply wasn't clear. The URL that I am getting information from looks like: example.com/example/file035_file_1_eng.txt. But in your answer, using $i will give me: example.com/example/file031_file_1_eng.text. Is there a way to use two different variables and increment them both?

Comment: @honestinjun I've added the urls that I get with the loop in my answer. Let me know if that's what you want to get. If that's not the case, please clarify what's the desired output.

Comment: I edited my first post. Sorry for the previous confusion. I'm pretty new to command line.